# WPF countdown timer and DispatchTimer skips seconds

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I'm having some trouble with my code. I'm trying to create a countdown timer that resets every "x" seconds. When the timer reaches zero, it performs some task that can potentially take some time. Once the task is complete, the timer should restart and repeat this process. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace CamCap
{
    class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        private   DispatcherTimer _countDownTimer;

        private DateTime _now;

        private DateTime _next;

        private string _timer;

        private string _timeFound;

        private static int INTERVAL = 5; // interval
        public string Timer
        {
            get { return _timer; }
            set
            {
                _timer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Timer");
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {

            _countDownTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _countDownTimer.Tick += async (o, e) => await countdownTimer();
            _countDownTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1); // every second
            _countDownTimer.IsEnabled = true;
            _countDownTimer.Start();
            restartCountdown();
        }

        private async Task countdownTimer()
        {

            var timeRemaining = _next - DateTime.Now;
            var t = timeRemaining.Hours + "h " + timeRemaining.Minutes + "m " + timeRemaining.Seconds + "s";
            this.Timer = t;
            var secondsRemaining = (int)timeRemaining.TotalSeconds;

            if (secondsRemaining <= 0)
            {
                _countDownTimer.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Executing...");
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    // do  stuff that might take some time
                    validate( );

                });
               _countDownTimer.Start();
            }

        }


        public async void validate( )
        {

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {

            }); 
            // restart timer
            restartCountdown();
        }


        private void restartCountdown()
        {
            _now = DateTime.Now;
            _next = _now.AddSeconds(INTERVAL);
        }

    }
}
```

Also, the countdown is displayed on a Label called Timer. The problem I'm facing, is that when the countdown starts anew, some of the seconds are skipped and won't show intermediate seconds. For example:  from 9 seconds, it'll show 6 seconds but will never show 8 or 7.

I'm thinking it has something to do with how async/await works because the DispatchTimer was started in the main thread. I'm not sure how to solve this.